# Two values to search in the same cell

Tags: excel

Can the below be shorten up? It’s basically to count if “dr” or “ba” are in cell E2180;

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(dr)",E2180)),"1",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(ba)",E2180)),"1",""))
```

Many thanks

Comment: John, consider about accepting answers. It's the way of saying "thanks" on stackoverflow. See this link for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"(dr)","(ba)"},E2180)),1,"")`

you can extend that for 3 or more values

Comment: Hey, too quick Nanashi! - I just changed it - thanks

Comment: +1 nice one! didn't know it doesn't require array entry!

Comment: @simoco, Yes if you used a range containing criteria like A1:B1 in place of {"(dr)","(ba)"} then it **DOES** require array entry

Answer (score 0):

And you can try this one, using countif:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(E2180;{"*(dr)*";"*(da)*"}));1;"")
```